# How do I install mod_pagespeed using apt-get?

Tags: apt, apache-httpd

I remember seeing an article at one time on how to do this, but now I can't find it. I have seen other install directions. I want to make sure I can easily update it via apt.

Answer (score 3):

[There is no Debian `mod_pagespeed` package yet](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=602316), it seems to be quite a difficult feat.

That said, Google apparently [provides 32bit and 64bit `.deb` archives via `developers.google.com`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/download?hl=de#mod_pagespeed), which you can install with, say,

```
# dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-beta_current_amd64.deb
```

but which are not supported by the Debian project.

However, Google [does seem to provide an `apt` repository,](http://ilovett.com/blog/programming/mod-pagespeed)<sup>**(1)**</sup> and **installing the binary mentioned above** adds this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mod-pagespeed.list`, which *probably* gets you updates via `apt` and the like:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/mod-pagespeed/deb/ stable main
```

**(1)** I couldn't find any *official mention* of this repository (only [this German (sorry!) blog post](http://www.tobis-home.de/blog/2011/03/apache2-mod-pagespeed-im-einsatz.html)), so I would not count on it.  But anyway, third-party `deb`s and repos are always to be taken with a pinch of salt.

**PS** [This might be terribly slow.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=93409)

Comment: They also import their key as part of the post install script. You can unpack the deb and get the key out of it. Without adding the key, the packages will throw signing warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of sr_'s answer, here's how to do it in a shell.

***Warning***: The filename in the second line is **not** `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Please scroll to the right if it's cut off.

```
sudo -i
echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/mod-pagespeed/deb/ stable main'> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mod-pagespeed.list
apt-get update
apt-get install mod-pagespeed-stable
exit
```

There's also a `mod-pagespeed-beta`, if you'd like to live on the edge.